# jQuery .has() Target Different Element

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty new at jQuery and would like to get better. I tried to come up with this snippet of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#result-list").has("div#boom")(
        function() {
        $("div.page-navigation").css("display", "none"));
    });
});
```

I'm trying to make div.page-navigation disappear if ul#result-list has div#boom. No luck so far despite searching all over the web. Am I far off? Thanks for the hel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.has()` returns the matched dom elements, not a true or false boolean value. Instead, check the `length` property to determine if `div#boom` exists in `#result-list`.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("ul#result-list").has("div#boom").length) {
    $("div.page-navigation").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you guys for the prompt answer. I've been trying to figure this out for the past 3 hours...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if($('ul#result-list:has(div#boom)').length > 0) {
      $('div.page-navigation').hide();
   }
}
```

This will hide the page navigation div if there's at least one result-list item that has a boom div element.

Answer (score 0):

The only issues I can see, really, is that you're not chaining methods:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#result-list").has("div#boom")(
        function() {
        $("div.page-navigation").css("display", "none"));
    });
});
```

Which means that after `.has()` you're opening a parenthesis that isn't attached to a method. I'd suggest that you should try and use an `if` statement, rather than trying to chain, in this instance. I'd post my thoughts, but [@DNR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505436/jquery-has-target-different-element/5505498#5505498), and [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505436/jquery-has-target-different-element/5505513#5505513), got there first.