# Start fancybox on all anchor tags with image inside

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am having issues with starting up fancybox. I'd like to use fancybox on all images inside #content block. All the images have following code:

```
<a href="img.jpg">
<img title="title" src="img.jpg" alt="alt" width="225" height="169">
</a>
```

I don't want to use special class for the link (pictures are managed by user through tinymce). I tried:

```
$("#content a").has('img').fancybox({
..fancybox settings
});
```

and as well

```
$("#content a img").parent('a').fancybox({
..fancybox settings
});
```

without any luck. `$("#content a").has('img').hide()` works perfectly - so selecting the proper element is just fine.

**EDIT:** Maybe for better understanding: using `$("#content a")` works, but works on all `<a>` tags, meaning that as well simple links like `<a href="google.com">google</a>` are "fancyboxed".

**EDIT2:** HTML code:

```
<div id="content">
<p>Lots of text.
    <a href="href">
        <img src="src" alt="alt" width="225" height="169" />
    </a>
</p>
<p>another text</p>
<p>more text <a href="http://www.google.com">Simple link which should not be opened by fancybox</a></p>
</div>
```

Thx for any ideas.

Comment: can u explain more wat u want?

Comment: I'd like to open all the images in fancybox. So I have to turn the fancybox on all a tags, that have an image inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally got it working. I just added the length attribute to your's codes thanks to  [jQuery .has() Target Different Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505436/jquery-has-target-different-element).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#content a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).has('img').length) {
        $(this).fancybox();
    }
});
```

I have to say, that I don't know why the `$('#content a').has('img').hide();` didn't work. When I "cleaned" the code as much as I could, it worked. I was unable to find which element caused the problem though.

Answer (score 4):

`$('a').has('img')` *should* return all the `a` elements that has `img` elements so it's really weird that it doesn't work. How about this:

```
$('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).has('img')) {
        $(this).fancybox();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should enable fancybox with all the images under div with id content.

```
 $("#content img").fancybox({
    ..fancybox settings
    });
```

This should enable fancybox on all a tags whih has an image, inside the content div.

```
$("#content a").each(function(){
    if($(this).has("img"))
    {
        $(this).fancybox({
             //..fancybox settings
         });
    }
  });
```

Comment: thx for your answer, unfortunately this does not work. Here as well replacing `fancybox` with `hide()` function hides ALL a tags. I have to check if my code is realy valid, because this is just strange.

Answer (score 2):

Why not directly target those links *linking to images* instead of those that contain images in their content? That's probably what you need, since Fancybox is used to show large images.

That is easily done:

```
//build a selector that targets all links ending in an image extension
var thumbnails = 'a[href$=".gif"],a[href$=".jpg"],a[href$=".jpeg"],a[href$=".png"],a[href$=".GIF"],a[href$=".JPG"],a[href$=".JPEG"],a[href$=".PNG"]';

//add "fancybox" class to those (this step could be skipped if you want) and group them under a same "rel" to enable previous/next buttons once in Fancybox
jQuery(thumbnails).addClass("fancybox").attr("rel","lightbox");

//call fancybox
jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a rel="example_group" href="img.jpg">
<img title="title" src="img.jpg" alt="alt" width="225" height="169">
</a>


$("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
..fancybox settings


});
```

or

```
$("#content a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
..fancybox settings


});
```

try using this give a rel to anchor

Comment: Seeing as he doesn't want to use a class, I don't think the rel attribute is any better.

Comment: but he needs to open all the images using fancybox as per his question

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, I don't really care if the images are in common gallery, so the others got it right.

Comment: @aGr can u post the id=content ... is it a div or ...... can u post the code of it